# Guest make http request for some html file, how can host capture response result before it return to guest

Tags: html, http, networking, virtualbox

I want to figure out whether the firewall of guest OS modify the response html file. So I need to compare the html response files in guest and host os. But I cannot make two same requests separately in two OS. There will cause too many time or sid difference, but I want to focus on the content of the html file.

The method I came up with is that use guest make http request, and setup some server in host os and forward that request, and capture the response html file before return back to guest os.

P.S. About censorship problem.

Comment: I just use python module urllib2 to set the request and read html file from certain url in two OS.

Comment: Then you should post that, it is currently very difficult to tell what exactly you are asking

Comment: The sample is as follows: t = urllib2.urlopen(http://www.google.com) ; html = t.read(); Then I write these html to some files and do this operation both in host and guest. At last, use linux command "diff" to see the difference.

Comment: My current thinking is just making a request from guest os. Since I am using Virtualbox, I want to use NAT network configuration to listen on certain ports of guest and capture the request from host either by wireshark or tcpdump